# How to (re)create an USB 3 header interface PCB?

Tags: usb, pcb-design, usb-device

I would like to start a "small" project. Create an USB 3 version of an existing USB 2 PCB.

On the PCB there is only 2 USB connectors, a capacitor and a USB header (to connect to the USB controller). The PCB has a special shape (not a rectangle or square).

I'm not an engineer, this is the first time I'm trying to do this. Not sure where to start or what to search to help me start.

1. Which software should I use to do this (to design the PCB)?
2. Where do I buy the parts to do this?
3. What should I search on the Web to help me started?

Picture of what I want to (re)create (in USB 3):
[image: Top view]
[image: Angled view]
[image: Side view]
[image: Back view]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words and all that :-)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I think this question is indeed very vague, you should at least give your overview (maybe a block scheme) of the design and work from there.

Comment: Unless I completely misread the OP, they just want to make a usb 3.0 header adapter. It plugs into an internal usb connector, just like a internal usb cable would.

Comment: @Anindo Ghosh Uploaded pictures....

Comment: @Jesús Castañé Updated question with more details.

Comment: @clabacchio It sould be more clear now.

Comment: @Alex Nominated the question for reopening.

Comment: I think this question is not yet ready for reopening, because the first two questions are about general circuit design, and the third is like "can you tell me how to do my project?"

Answer (score 2):

There are no special requirements for trace routing, aside from the usual high speed data line routing specifications. The same that USB 2 requires.

Keep differential pairs together (D+/D-, SSTX+/SSTX-, etc), and keep them the same length, as much as you can. Since the pinout of a usb 3.0 jack keeps them together, and the pinout of the header does as well, it should be simple. Heck, USB 3.0 is backwards compatible with 2.0, you don't even have to route the new pins. You could make a 2.0 jack to 3.0 Header, or a 3.0 jack to 2.0 header.

USB 3.0 header adaptors are pretty much the same as USB 2.0, just with more pins.

[image]

You can find them made in many types as is (Google `USB 3 Header`):
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Uploaded pictures of what I'm trying to recerate...

Comment: I want to have USB 3 speeds too not just use an adapter with the old device. So I can't use the old hardware.

Comment: @AlexV It's simple. Since you want to make one from scratch, you need a PCB routing software (I use Eagle), you need the footprints for the jacks you will use (look for the datasheets), and that's pretty much it. Look for questions on how to make a pcb. Then send it out to get it made.